# Forcing Ubuntu to always load NVIDIA GPU drivers

Tags: boot, 18.04, drivers, graphics, nvidia-prime

Occasionally when rebooting Ubuntu, the system loads the Intel GPU drivers instead of the NVIDIA GPU, despite always leaving the NVIDIA profile selected in PRIME. I know I can change the selected profile of PRIME through the following code:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

So is there a way to insert this piece of code somewhere in the booting sequence of Ubuntu (18.04 btw) before the system loads the Graphics drivers? Or is there some other way to force the computer to **always** boot Nvidia?

Thanks in advance for any effort put into solving this :)

Comment: How do you know that "the system loads the Intel GPU drivers instead of the NVIDIA GPU"?

Comment: When I go into **System settings > Details > About** it shows _Intel HD Graphics_ ,instead of _Geforce..._ when it boots correctly

Comment: This is not a reliable source of information ;-) Check it in the Nvidia X Server application.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you meant by unreliable, in the Nvidia X Server app it says it's configured for the Nvidia Gpu, but when I run 'nvidia-smi' to see what is running on the Gpu, it doesn't show anything. That's why I think the drivers are not being loaded at all.